# Check the existence of a HashMap key

Tags: java, hashmap, micro-optimization, containskey

In Java, having a HashMap fully filled in with data of such form:

```
HashMap<Integer, int[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>(1000000, 1);
```

what is faster when checking the existence of a random key, say 100:

```
if (map.get(100) == null))
```

or

```
if (!map.containsKey(100))
```

?

Question is interesting from the micro-optimization point of view.

Comment: Why don't you simple test it?

Comment: I did, but it gives all the time different execution times which are in some interval and more-or-less the same. So I have no idea what is really faster.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `containsKey` should be **very slightly** slower because it results in an extra function call (it just calls `getEntry`) (it could get optimised away, I'm not sure whether Java will do so). `containsKey` looks like:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
  return getEntry(key) != null;
}
```

But note that `containsKey` could on the other hand be very slightly **faster** on other `Map` implementations (but probably not those in the standard Java API).

Generally my implementations look like: (avoiding the need for `containsKey`)

```
int[] arr = map.get(100);
if (arr == null) // doesn't exist
  // do stuff
else // exists
  // do stuff with arr
```

The below would **definitely** be slower than the above: (if the items you look for exist a reasonable amount of the time)

```
if (!map.containsKey(100)) // doesn't exist
  // do stuff
else // exists
{
  int[] arr = map.get(100);
  // do stuff with arr
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to zvzdhk for providing the source of `containsKey`. I should actually have checked.

Answer (score 6):

Actually both approaches are the same. If you look in `java.util.HashMap` source code you can find next containsKey realization:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getEntry(key) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two differs only in `return` type except that `map.get(key)` may return you `null` in case if its a key, however `map.containsKey(key)` will return you `boolean` which could be used to distingush the two possible cases of `map.get(key)` returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between this two approaches. The main difference only what you are going to do next. If you need the value then, of course by get you will have the value.